# Align words in column

Tags: c#, words

I'm quite new to C#, so I got a task to allign words in columns.
So basically I've got a notepad with text in it for example:
`wordone word two... wordmillion` and lets say there are 6lines of them. I need to set them in order so it would look like:
`word one         word two    word three
                                   wordjosdjfjfisio anotherword otherword`

That each other word would start at a place like shown(extra space from longest word in first column and etc.) I tried to explain at as clearly as I could, any tips/ideas how do it? I think padright is the solution?
P.S. sorry if the layout is wrong, I'm quite new to this community.

Comment: In what context are you working? Are you using ASP.Net, WinForms, WPF  or something else?

Comment: I'm in UNI at the moment, I'm reading the lines from .txt file, working on Visual studio 2015 platform. I have to put the alligned text to .txt file back(of course different one)

Comment: You need to know the limits of your data: how long are the columns allowed to grow? And what to do when the words get longer? Also: what is the purpose? display, editing, printing, storage? Maybe other controls like DataGridView or Listview would help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are on the right track here!

First of all, here is the documentation for PadRight:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Taken from this MSDN explanation, we can see the following useful example:

```
string str = "forty-two";
char pad = '.';

Console.WriteLine(str.PadRight(15, pad));    // Displays "forty-two......".
Console.WriteLine(str.PadRight(2,  pad));    // Displays "forty-two".
```

So a psuedo code algorithm for your answer could be the following - let me know if you need more explanation:

1. Read all of the words in your file into a string array
2. Find the length of the longest word, lets call it maxLength
3. Go over all words and write them formatted in a table. You want to write them row by row, printing a newline after each row. For each row, take the number of columns you want to display (3 in your example).
4. Instead of writing the word itself, you should use word.PadRight(maxLength + 1, ' ');

Note - MaxLength + 1 is just so a space will be shown after your longest word as well. I hope this is enough info to get you on your way. Feel free to ask any follow up questions!

Comment: I put all of the lines in to List<string>, once I read the lines I divide them in words, while using foreach cycle. So as I understood, I just write out the first column, find the longest word and start writing the second column in maxlength+1 using padright? Sorry if I understood it wrong, I want to be sure. EXTRA EDIT: there might be for example only two words in first line, second line 100 and etc.. So the number varies.

Comment: Regarding your extra edit - can you please explain all the cases of the problem you are trying to solve? What determines how many rows and how many words in each row? I'd like to understand exactly what input you are getting to provide you with a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use \t   (tab) in Console.Writeline();
Example

```
Console.WriteLine("word one\t\tword two\t\tword three");
Console.WriteLine("wordjosdjfjfisio\tanotherword\totherword");
```

Comment: That's a great idea, but what if I had like millions lines and a word like 30characters long? Would it work?

Comment: While this will format the lines nicely, it will not have the effect OP wants, since the two lines will not be aligned with one another.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example making use of LINQ:

```
var text = "word_1_1   word_1_2 word_1_3\r\nsome_word_2_1 another_word_2_2  word_2_3\n word_3_1";

var words = text.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split('\n').Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, " +", " ").Split(' '));
var lengths = words.Select(x => x.Select(y => y.Length));
var maxColumns = lengths.Max(x => x.Count());
var widths = lengths
    .Select(x => x.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, maxColumns)).Take(maxColumns))
    .Aggregate(Enumerable.Repeat(0, maxColumns), (m, x) => { var t = x.ToArray(); m = m.Select((y, i) => y > t[i] ? y : t[i]); return m; });
var paddedLines = words.Select(x => String.Join(" ", x.Zip(widths, (a, b) => a.PadRight(b)).ToArray()));
var paddedText = String.Join("\r\n", paddedLines.ToArray());
```